# Rails SQL Query with group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, group-by, sum, find

My table ORDER in MySQL,and Class Order: has_many :product

```
id     +     name    +     price  +   amount   +  product_id
1      |     orde    |    100     |     5      |    1
2      |     orde    |    50      |     2      |    2
3      |     orde    |    -100    |     -2     |    1
```

I want to find the answer like this:

```
**"Right Answer"**
id     +    name    +    price   +   amount   +   product_id
1      |    orde    |    100     |     3      |     1
2      |    orde    |    50      |     2      |     2
```

the column "amount" plus where the column "product_id" had same product_id, like amount = (id:1)amount + (id:3)amount = 3.

when I use :

```
@order.group(:product_id).sum(:amount)
```

the MySQL answer is :

```
 amount   +    product_id
  3       |      1
  2       |      2
```

and when I use :

```
@order.group(:product_id)
```

the MySQL answer is :

```
id     +     name    +   price   +   amount   +  product_id
1      |     orde    |   -100    |     -2     |    1
2      |     orde    |    50     |      2     |    2
```

How will I design the 'Active Record Query Interface' to find the "Right Answer" like the first table? I am using Rails framework and MySQL.

Comment: Why do you want the extra three columns? I think they are meaningless.

Comment: @Yanhao I think the id and name are meaningless.But I want to know the product's price when I create the order.Can you help me find "price","amount","product_id" columns?